# Multiple symbol definitions when using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I have a autotools project that I've added a Visual Studio solution and project file for, and everything builds fine until I get to the linking stage. I get [this output](http://pastebin.com/nAJTsLCz). An excerpt:

```
error LNK2005: "public: static bool const std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::is_signed" already defined in abstract_syntax_graph.obj
```

Basically, a bunch of multiple definitions for C++ standard library stuff. I'm guessing there is something wrong with my project configuration in Visual Studio but I have no idea what would control whatever feature that is.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar errors when compiling a project under VS2015 using the /Za flag. Note that this worked fine under VS2013, but wouldn't build until I removed /Za from the VS2015 project.

This doesn't seem like an actual answer to me, I would have thought that there should be no issue disabling language extensions.